# "PolynomialError: only univariate polynomials are allowed" when solving a system of inequalities

Tags: python, sympy

I want to find the interval of following two constants `cons1` and `cons2`
I wrote the follwing code

```
 from sympy import Poly
 from sympy import Abs
 from sympy.solvers.inequalities import solve_rational_inequalities
 from sympy.abc import x
 cons1=2*((x+2)**2)-Abs(x)-1
 cons2=exp(2*x+1)-2.5
 solve_rational_inequalities([[((Poly(cons1), Poly(1, x)), '<='), (Poly(cons2), Poly(1, x)), '<=')]])
```

but because of Abs I am getting:

```
PolynomialError: only univariate polynomials are allowed
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback of error messages. And for future reference: You can format your code with the {} button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. `2*((x+2)**2) - Abs(x) - 1` is not a polynomial in x. Neither is `exp(2*x+1) - 2.5`. The methods of `solve_rational_inequalities` do not apply  to such functions.

If you try to cheat mathematics by wrapping those expressions in Poly, all that happens is that SymPy will make them polynomials with respect to `x` **and** `Abs(x)` (or `exp(2*x+1)`, etc). That's a kind of a polynomial, but not a polynomial with respect to x, which is what `solve_rational_inequalities` requires. Hence the error.

Bottom line: SymPy does not currently have an algorithm for solving systems of general inequalities. There is an algorithm for **rational inequalities**  and some other things listed on [inequality solvers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html) page, including `solve_univariate_inequality` (which allows general functions, but for one variable only).