# solve equalities and inequalities with multiple variables in python

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve the following problem:

```
 2*x + 4*y = 6 
 0 <= x <= 2
 0 <= y <= 1
```

I have tried sympy

```
from sympy import Poly
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import solve_rational_inequalities
from sympy.abc import x, y, z

solve_rational_inequalities([[
((Poly(2*x + 4*y ), 6), '=='),
((Poly(x), 2), '<='),
((Poly(y), 1), '<='),
((Poly(x), 0), '>='),
((Poly(y), 0), '>=')]])
```

but I got  Exception, polynomialError:

```
  only univariate polynomials are allowed
```

Is there any way to solve this with sympy or any other python library?

Comment: Why can't you use Sympy?

Comment: There will be one solution for every `1 <= x <= 2`. So, what is your expected result?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: You can't with SymPy. [Quoting a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49225260/1431750): SymPy does not currently have an algorithm for solving systems of general inequalities. There is an algorithm for rational inequalities and some other things listed on [inequality solvers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html) page, including `solve_univariate_inequality` (which allows general functions, **but for one variable only**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [python-constraint](https://github.com/python-constraint/python-constraint):

```
import constraint

problem = constraint.Problem()

problem.addVariable('x', range(2))
problem.addVariable('y', [1])

def our_constraint(x, y):
    if 2*x + 4*y == 6:
        return True

problem.addConstraint(our_constraint, ['x','y'])

solutions = problem.getSolutions()

for solution in solutions:
    print(solution)
```

Output:
`{'y': 1, 'x': 1}`